# Have nodejs module use files defined in the directory of the caller

Tags: node.js

I am defining a  Nodejs module, config.js, which will have all the logic to read the configuration file written in json.

I want to use this module else where in a different node module and have it use the configuration file defined in this different node module.

for eg:

```
var Config = require('config')

Config.getPoroperty('client.url')
```

Here the actual json file which has client.url defined in it, would be defined in the directory structure of the module where the Config module is used. The logic to read this json file is defined in config module

How do i achieve that?

Comment: I think the best thing to do would be to accept configuration upon instantiation.  But, I'm guessing this is more of a utility class?  In this case, why have a class at all?  Are you doing more than `getProperty()`?  If not, you can simply `require()` a JSON file directly.

Comment: yes i am going to have more than getProperty, getProperty is just an example, i want getProperty to look for a property in certain hierarchical sequence, something i want to abstract in a separate module.

Comment: You could try to find the file in `process.cwd()`, and only if not found revert to the one in the module itself?

Comment: @konquestor Why not pass in the file to load?  `var Config = require('config')('path/to/config.json');`

Comment: because i dont know the path/to  in advance config module is going to be a generic module which shall be used across several modules to read configuration files.